# Scaling out an azure app service vs container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure app service. It works great and scales when I need it to. Only issue is that scaling can take a few minutes. Would this scaling up/down be smaller if the application was deployed through docker?

Is there any example of this?

Answer (score 2):

No, it wouldn't significantly affect the time it takes to scale up\down. because under the hood its creating\removing vms. spinning up your application on that vm takes very little time compared to creating\configuring that vm.